# How can I use the test ive created to debug the code below ? What do I need to change in the code?

Tags: python, debugging, testing, test-suite

Ive made the testers here and they work fine in diagnosing the bug.

```
Heres the code for linked_list_from_list

def linked_list_from_list(items):
    ll = LinkedList()
    for i in items:
        ll.add_value(i)
    return ll

def test_empty():
    ll = LinkedList()
    assert ll.count_of(1) == 0

def test_zero():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(0) == 0

def test_one():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(2) == 1

def test_two():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(2) == 2

def test_bug():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(1) == 4
    
def test_small():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1])
    assert ll.count_of(1) == 1

def test_bug():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(1) == 4
    
def test_small():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1])
    assert ll.count_of(1) ==
```

and the results show an assertion error

but I don't know what to change in the main block of code here :

```
class LinkedList:
    """Stores data using a linked list"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Create a new, empty linked list"""
        self.head = None

    def add_value(self, value):
        """Add a new value to the head of the list
        :param value: the new value to store"""
        self.head = ListNode(value, self.head)

    def count_of(self, value):
        """Counts the number of occurrences of value in the list
        :param value: the value to count
        :returns: the number of occurrences of value in the list"""

        cursor = self.head
        count = 0
        
        if self.head is None:
            return 0
        
        while cursor.nextNode is not None:
            if cursor.value == value:
                count += 1
            cursor = cursor.nextNode

        return count
```

I know its something to do with the count_of function where in the case where there's a count of the digit 1 it returns 4.

Comment: You've missed something from the `assert` in `test_small`. What are the results of the tests? Also, please include the code for `linked_list_from_list()`.

Comment: Heres the code for linked_list_from_list

def linked_list_from_list(items):
    ll = LinkedList()
    for i in items:
        ll.add_value(i)
    return ll

def test_empty():
    ll = LinkedList()
    assert ll.count_of(1) == 0

def test_zero():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(0) == 0

def test_one():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(2) == 1

def test_two():
    ll = linked_list_from_list([1,2,2,3])
    assert ll.count_of(2) == 2

and the results show an assertion error

Comment: Please update the question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73407039/edit) button. Don't leave this code in your comment. Its unreadable there.

Comment: What if `cursor.value == value`, but there's no next node? Your code will return zero, but the correct answer is one.

Comment: @ForceBru I've tried this but it doesn't work  If cursor.nextNode is None: \n return 1

Comment: @quamrana All has been edited sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @aneesha, that `cursor.nextNode is None` doesn't necessarily mean that the number of occurrences of `value` is one. You should add a check `cursor.value == value` _before_ the loop as well.

Comment: @ForceBru I still don't understand the whole question at all oh well

Comment: @aneesha, try executing `count_of` by hand: 1. suppose `self.head = ListNode(5, None)`; 2. Enter `self.count_of(5)`; 3. `count = 0`; 4. `cursor.nextNode is None`, so the loop is skipped; 5. `return count`, so zero is returned. Does this make sense? What's missing here? Has this code _ever_ checked whether `cursor.value == value`? No, but it should have!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the purpose of `test_bug()`? The test itself seems to be wrong.